# How to fix This Error in MySQL #1932 - Table 'rowater.wp_postmeta' doesn't exist in engine

Tags: mysql

How to fix this mysql error  #1932 - Table 'rowater.wp_postmeta' doesn't exist in engine

Comment: Please share the query which gives the error. Have you confirmed the table does exist? What troubleshooting have you already tried?

Comment: Please add context, like: Are you sure the table `wp_postmeta` exists in database `rowater`?

Comment: I have an old mysql data folder where I have a database folder name like xyz this old folder I just copied from the old data folder and past in new xampp>mysql>data folder after paste I Now  I have database in phpmyadmin with all tables but tables are not oping on the click I am getting this Error #1932 - Table 'rowater.wp_links' doesn't exist in engine

Comment: You should better export db and then import db to the respective database

Comment: I don't have Exported file I have just database folder any solution